# SSIS - Procesar archivos modificados

Tags: sql-server, script, ssis

Buenas a ver si podéis echarme un cable,

Tengo un paquete de SSIS en el cual proceso unos archivos XML y meto la información que quiero en una o varias tablas.

Tengo una tarea SQL con la cual señalo los archivos que proceso y así, la próxima vez que se ejecuta el paquete, procesa los archivos nuevos.

El problema que tengo es que si modifico los datos de uno de los archivos o meto uno nuevo con el mismo nombre y sobrescribo el otro que había, SSIS no lo reconoce como nuevo y no me lo procesa.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La pregunta tiene pocos detalles, pero si ya estás usando el nombre del archivo, supongo que también podrías tomar la fecha de última modificación del archivo para comparar ambos valores. De tal forma, la tabla quedaría con la columna de nombre de archivo y fecha de última modificación.

Si te parece más fácil, puedes usar la fecha de procesamiento del archivo y tomar todos los que hayan sido modificados después de esa fecha. Aunque eso podría ser un problema si los archivos se crean en algún lugar distinto antes del proceso y se copian después del mismo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de momento he conseguido hacerlo de forma rudimentaria entre 2 carpetas y un .bat que me copia los archivos nuevos o modificados en otra carpeta y ssis me procesa los archivos de esta carpeta y me los borra, seguiré probando con lo de la fecha como me has puesto, a ver si lo consigo sacar.
Muchas gracias!